# jQuery Validation - валидация только после изменения поля input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, валидация

Здравствуйте, есть форма редактирования контактной информации и себе в личном кабинете:

```
<form id="form" action="about/changecontact" method="POST">
<div>
<label for="nick">Никнейм</label>
<input name="nick" id="nick" spellcheck="false" required type="text"  maxlength="20" value="<?=$userData['nick']?>" autocomplete="off">
</div>
<div>
<label for="phone">Телефон</label>
<input name="phone" id="phone" spellcheck="false" required type="text"  maxlength="20" value="<?=$userData['phone']?>" autocomplete="off">
</div>
<div>
<label for="email">E-mail</label>
<input name="email" id="email" spellcheck="false" required type="text" maxlength="20" value="<?=$userData['email']?>" autocomplete="off">
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Сохранить">
</form>
```

В полях формы уже подставлены телефон и электронная почта.
С помощью jQuery Validation проверяю форму на пустоту, минимальное количество символов, но также хочу проверить поля email и phone с помощью метода remote на существование в базе почты и телефона вот таким образом:

```
$().ready(function() {
$("#form").validate({
         rules: {
            phone: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 17,
            remote: {
                url: "ajaxcheck.php?check=phone",
                type: "post"
            }
         },
         email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: {
                url: "ajaxcheck.php?check=email",
                type: "post"
            }
         }
      },
      messages: {
         phone: {
            required: ""
            minlength: ""
            remote: ""
         },
         email: {
            required: "",
            email: "",
            remote: ""
      }
  });
});
```

Проверяю:

```
switch($_GET['check']){
    case 'email':
    $email = $db->select("SELECT `Residents`.`email`, `Staff`.`email` FROM `Residents`, `Staff` WHERE `Residents`.`email` = {?} OR `Staff`.`email` = {?} LIMIT 1", array($data['email'], $data['email']));
    if(count($email)) echo "false";
    else echo "true";
    break;
    case 'phone':
    $phone = $db->select("SELECT `Residents`.`phone`, `Staff`.`phone` FROM `Residents`, `Staff` WHERE `Residents`.`phone` = {?} OR `Staff`.`phone` = {?}   LIMIT 1", array($data['phone'], $data['phone']));
    if(count($phone)) echo "false";
    else echo "true";
    break;
}
```

Вопрос в том как проверять на валидность поля email и phone только после того, как они были изменены? В данной ситуации, если пользователь зайдет на страницу и захочет поменять никнейм, то валидатор будет проверять и телефон и почту. Но так как такие адреса уже есть в базе у пользователя не получится поменять информацию. Я не силен в javascript, поэтому прошу помощи. Как проверять форму на валидность  без проверки полей, которые не были изменены? (Также, если пользователь начнет менять, например, почту example@example.com поставит вместо .com - .ru, а затем обратно напишет .com валидатор не проверял это поле?)

Answer (score 1):

Перед отправкой (событие `onsubmit`) - слать AJAX запрос серверу, проверять, слать клиенту `success`, затем отправлять форму на сервер.

Comment: Если тебе не трудно и есть время - опиши это, пожалуйста, кодом, на моем примере. Уже несколько часов пытаюсь это сделать - все бестолку, очень слаб в яваскрипте

Comment: `$("form").on("submit",function(){$.post("url",{f_name:$("input").val()},function(response){if(response.error == "false"){return true;}else{return false;}},"json");})` - на клиенте. Проверка должна вызываться по адресу `url`, `response` - ответ от сервера. Сервер должен отправлять JSON